# VI editor “ESC” + X” do not work correctly

Tags: unix, editor, vi, hp-ux

For some reason when I am on VI MODE editing a file, when I do a SHIFT+A to append and write something next to that, example tabs 81234. When I try to do ESC then x to delete the 1234 it doesn't work. First when I hit ESC cursor stays next to the 4, example tabs 81234[] when it should go back to 4, so hitting x wont delete the character only if I go up or down arrows i then can use x do delete.

I have other environments like UAT or MO with the exact same configuration and there it works with no issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is your TERM is set incorrectly. I just tested this on HP-UX 11.23 ia64 and it worked just fine.